# plsql function with cursor

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am writing one plsql function, in this function I want to add one cursor.
cursor is depending on value from one of the tables. 
If i write anything before cursor its giving me error.
How to write that.
Below is my sample code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_ResolveValueExpression(inRowId NUMBER)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
      isRangeValue     PLS_INTEGER;
      ExpressionValue  VARCHAR2(100);
      FinalRangeValue  VARCHAR2(100);
      g_ExchangeType   VARCHAR2(100) := 'BSE';
      g_TradeMode      VARCHAR2(100) := 'SQUP';
      rangeTypeNrageField        VARCHAR2(10);


      SELECT RANGE_TYPE || ' ' || Range_field
        INTO rangeTypeNrageField
        FROM Range_Header
       WHERE RANGE_ID = inRowId;


      CASE rangeTypeNrageField
        WHEN 'RL EXCHANGE' THEN
            CURSOR c_RangeValueDetails IS
            SELECT R.LOV_VALUE LOV_VALUE,
                   R.RANGE_VAL_TYPE RANGE_VAL_TYPE,
                   R.RANGE_VALUE RANGE_VALUE
              FROM Range_Value_Details R
             WHERE R.RANGE_ID = inRowId
                   AND R.LOV_VALUE = g_ExchangeType;


        WHEN 'RL TRDMODE' THEN
            CURSOR c_RangeValueDetails IS
            SELECT R.LOV_VALUE LOV_VALUE,
                   R.RANGE_VAL_TYPE RANGE_VAL_TYPE,
                   R.RANGE_VALUE RANGE_VALUE
              FROM Range_Value_Details R
             WHERE R.RANGE_ID = inRowId
                   AND R.LOV_VALUE = g_TradeMode;
      END CASE;

        BEGIN

          FOR i IN c_RangeValueDetails 
            LOOP
              IF i.RANGE_VAL_TYPE = 'R' THEN
                  ExpressionValue := F_ResolveValueExpression(i.RANGE_VALUE);
              ELSE
                  ExpressionValue := i.RANGE_VALUE;
              END IF;
            End Loop;

        RETURN FinalRangeValue;
        END;
```

if i commment select statement before cursor it works.
By my case statement is depending on my select.
How to achieve this.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the `select` or `case` before the `begin`; they don't belong in the declaration section. You could define each cursor in its own sub-block, but then you'd have to repeat the loop code in each of those sub-blocks too.

Rather than define two cursors you could do a join to decide which column to check. Something like this (untested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_ResolveValueExpression(inRowId NUMBER)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
      isRangeValue     PLS_INTEGER;
      ExpressionValue  VARCHAR2(100);
      FinalRangeValue  VARCHAR2(100);
      g_ExchangeType   VARCHAR2(100) := 'BSE';
      g_TradeMode      VARCHAR2(100) := 'SQUP';

      CURSOR c_RangeValueDetails IS
        SELECT R.LOV_VALUE LOV_VALUE,
               R.RANGE_VAL_TYPE RANGE_VAL_TYPE,
               R.RANGE_VALUE RANGE_VALUE
          FROM Range_Header H
          JOIN Range_Value_Details R
            ON R.RANGE_ID = H.RANGE_ID
           AND ((H.RANGE_TYPE = 'RL' AND H.Range_field = 'EXCHANGE' 
                 AND R.LOV_VALUE = g_ExchangeType)
            OR (H.RANGE_TYPE = 'RL' AND H.Range_field = 'TRDMODE'
                 AND R.LOV_VALUE = g_TradeMode))
         WHERE H.RANGE_ID = inRowId;

BEGIN
  FOR i IN c_RangeValueDetails
...
```

Or if you prefer, since your two original cursors are the same apart from the filter value, you could (as you suggested) do the select separately and then pass that value to a parameratised cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_ResolveValueExpression(inRowId NUMBER)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
      isRangeValue     PLS_INTEGER;
      ExpressionValue  VARCHAR2(100);
      FinalRangeValue  VARCHAR2(100);
      g_ExchangeType   VARCHAR2(100) := 'BSE';
      g_TradeMode      VARCHAR2(100) := 'SQUP';
      rangeTypeNrageField        VARCHAR2(10);

      CURSOR c_RangeValueDetails (c_rangeTypeNrageField varchar2) IS
        SELECT R.LOV_VALUE LOV_VALUE,
               R.RANGE_VAL_TYPE RANGE_VAL_TYPE,
               R.RANGE_VALUE RANGE_VALUE
          FROM Range_Value_Details R
         WHERE R.RANGE_ID = inRowId
           AND R.LOV_VALUE = CASE c_rangeTypeNrageField
                 WHEN 'RL EXCHANGE' THEN g_ExchangeType
                 WHEN 'RL TRDMODE' THEN g_TradeMode END;
BEGIN
    SELECT RANGE_TYPE || ' ' || Range_field
      INTO rangeTypeNrageField
      FROM Range_Header
     WHERE RANGE_ID = inRowId;

     FOR i IN c_RangeValueDetails (rangeTypeNrageField)
...
```

Or evaluate the case statement earlier with:

```
...
      CURSOR c_RangeValueDetails (c_lov_value varchar2) IS
        SELECT R.LOV_VALUE LOV_VALUE,
               R.RANGE_VAL_TYPE RANGE_VAL_TYPE,
               R.RANGE_VALUE RANGE_VALUE
          FROM Range_Value_Details R
         WHERE R.RANGE_ID = inRowId
           AND R.LOV_VALUE = c_lov_value;
BEGIN
    SELECT RANGE_TYPE || ' ' || Range_field
      INTO rangeTypeNrageField
      FROM Range_Header
     WHERE RANGE_ID = inRowId;

     FOR i IN c_RangeValueDetails (CASE rangeTypeNrageField
                 WHEN 'RL EXCHANGE' THEN g_ExchangeType
                 WHEN 'RL TRDMODE' THEN g_TradeMode END)
...
```

You could use an implicit cursor for loop rather than an explicit (in the declare section) cursor; [see the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm) for the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...... cant i just declare cursor before begin ....  then write my select statement and then inside case assign values to cursor.... cause the code above is just small sample ... i will need to fetch data from diff tables ... so will not be possible to write in join ...

Comment: @user1515118 - yes, I've updated my answer with an example. I'm still assuming though that the two cursors are identical apart from filter values. If they actually join different tables depending on the range header data then it gets more complicated, and you might need to switch to the open-fetch-close method rather than a simple cursor for-loop.